# Why do I get "is not a function" error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I want to write my test classes for server app. I need to refactor my routers to controller arch. 
I return functions on controller's return value. But on my router I see Error. Do you have any idea? Which point am I passing?

Controller:

```
const express = require('express');

const controller = (Project) => {
    const projectMidlleware = require('../middleware/v1/projectMiddleware')(Project)
    const put = (req, res, next) => {
        projectMidlleware.create(req.query.name, (project) => {
            res.status(200).send(project.api_key);
            next();
        });
    }
    const findProject = (req, res, next) => {
        const apikey = req.headers["s-apikey"] || req.query.apikey || req.body.apikey;
        projectMidlleware.findByApikey(apikey, (err, project) => {
            if (err) {
                next({
                    message: err.message,
                    code: 500
                });
                return;
            }
            req.body.project = project;
            next();
        });
    }

    return {
        put,
        findProject
    }
}
module.exports = controller;
```

Router:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const projectController = require('../../controllers/projectController');
const profileController = require('../../controllers/profileController');

//return profiles for project
router.get("/",
  projectController.findProject(),
  profileController.get()
);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Where r u using `controller` in route ? `module.exports = { controller };`

Comment: just tried, didnt effect.

Comment: `const projectController = require('../../controllers/projectController')();` You have a function that returns an object with methods but you don't call the function and the methods exist on the returned object, not the function itself.

Comment: @JaredSmith is right. I think this is a strange design choice tbh.

Comment: I'm new at node and javascript. I've written my middleware with modules(routers and some middleware). But when I wanted to write my tests, I coulnd't choose a pattern or I couldn't find best practice. I found a tutorial on pluralsight (node-js-express-rest-web-services). He refactored his objects like this. End of the refactoring, he will pass the mock objects to controllers... But any recomendation would be great!

Comment: can you edit your question and post the complete error message you get?

Comment: Actuall, It'has been fixed with @JaredSmith's warning. Jared could you please post an answer, I could check it solved.

Comment: @atasoyh done and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const projectController = require('../../controllers/projectController')();
```

You have a function that returns an object with methods but you don't call the function and the methods exist on the returned object, not the function itself. This pattern is fairly common in node but I would actually do this for clarity:

```
const projectController = require('../../controllers/projectController');
const controller = projectController();
```

and then use that.